# Howto check against zsh script's parameter in a pattern or not

Tags: shell-script, zsh

A zsh script that run: `script.zsh nameabc01`, in `script.zsh` I need to check against that if `nameabc01` is in this pattern `na*abc*` or not to continue do something or decide to exit script.

How can we achieve that?

and to extend this question, how can we achieve that by checking against a list of pattern in a file (separated by newline)?

Comment: Why did you tag bash? Do you have a confusingly named bash script called "script.zsh", or can/should answers be specific to zsh?

Comment: How is the parameter passed? Obviously "nameabc01" matches the pattern; is the parameter input by the user? from another operation? Is it in a variable by time we need to check it?

Comment: script run in terminal so it's in command line, user type `nameabc01`. It also can be extend to `bash`. Because it's the first argument so we can check against it in `$1` I guess. We can also extend to a list of pattern from a file that separated by newline.

Answer (score 4):

Test that there are arguments and that the first argument matches some glob pattern:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
if (( # == 0 )); then
   print >&2 "Usage: $0 na*abc* ..."
   exit 1
fi
if [[ $1 != na*abc* ]]; then
   print >&2 "not ok"
   exit 1
fi
```

(Yes, I indent shell scripts at three spaces and no I never ever put `*.zsh` or `*.sh` extensions on them) which can be tested:

```
% ./argchecker
Usage: ./argchecker na*abc* ...
% ./argchecker wombat
not ok
% ./argchecker na1abc1
% ./argchecker na1111111111abc1111111111
%
```

If you want to allow `na1abc1` but disallow `na1111111111abc1111111111` you will need to used `?` instead of `*` or instead switch to a regular expression match with `=~` and a suitable regular expression.

Reading a list of patterns from a file is also possible but requires a bit more code for the necessary logic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
if (( # == 0 )); then
   print >&2 "Usage: $0 todofixme ..."
   exit 1
fi
globs=(${(f)"$(< patternfile)"})
ret=1
for g in $globs; do
    if [[ $1 == $~g ]]; then
       ret=0
       break
    fi
done
if (( ret == 1 )); then
   print >&2 "not ok"
   exit 1
fi
```

And the `patternfile` and some testing.

```
% cat patternfile
cat*
*bat
% ./pargchecker fish
not ok
% ./pargchecker catfish
% ./pargchecker wombat
%
```

The docs in `zshexpn(1)` and `zshparam(1)` are probably work a peek, or existing code in the `$fpath[-1]` directory.

Comment: How to keep track the pattern found in the file so that we can use a specific config to do an action against that specific pattern. May be parse a specific `.conf` file that contain a list of commands. we can extend to a list of pattern files and each mached pattern in a pattern file we can have an action on a specific `.conf` file.

Comment: probably with an associative array, see `zshparam(1)`. but that's sounding like a different question.

Comment: I'll open another question for this. I'll need to keep tracking all the materials that I need to complete some tasks. If you have solution, an open answered is welcome and appriciated.