# Check zsh script's argument against pattern in multiple files and keep tracking of matched pattern for other tasks

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh

This is extended question of [Howto check against zsh script's parameter in a pattern or not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/465105/howto-check-against-zsh-scripts-parameter-in-a-pattern-or-not/465135?noredirect=1#comment847183_465135)

While the link above solved the problem that a zsh script check agaist its first argument to list of patterns in a file separated by newline. I'd like to extend it as:

1. Check against patterns that in multiple files in multiple folders that probably in an array of folders.
2. Keep tracking of that matched pattern to do another task, i.e: call a `.conf` that setup something else.

While I ask this question, I still in multitasks and will update it later, if you have a solution, I'll much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files=($^array_of_folders/**/*.pattern(.N)) # assuming pattern files
                                            # have a .pattern extension
pattern="($(cat -- $files | paste -sd '|' -))"
if [[ $1 = $~pattern ]]; then
   print -r -- "$1 matches $pattern"
fi
```

Though if you want to know which of the patterns matched, you'd need:

```
files=($^array_of_folders/**/*.pattern(.N))
patterns=(${(f)"$(cat -- $files)"})
matching_patterns=()
for pattern ($patterns) {
   [[ $1 = $~pattern ]] && matching_patterns+=$pattern
}
print -r -- "$1 matched by $#matching_patterns patterns: $matching_patterns"
```

Comment: What would you define array_of_folders? Something like `array_of_folders=(~/fder1 ~/smt/fder2 /tmp/fder3)`? Also pattern is `$1` - first argument of zsh script: `script.zsh my_pattern`

Comment: @TuyenPham, that `array_of_folders` is meant to be the _array of folders_ you refer to in your question. And yes `array_of_folders=(~/fder1 ~/smt/fder2 /tmp/fder3)` could be one way to define it. In your question, you say `$1` is the string to match against patterns, not a pattern.

Comment: Ah yes, correct, $1 is string to match against patterns in files that inside folders.